# Правильная вёрстка сайта Materialize CSS

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, materialize-css

Помогите с исправлением ошибок в вёрстке.
Как это можно сделать более правильно с точки зрения Materialize CSS?
[Моя страница](https://divinytytoffee.github.io/Laba3Web/index.html).
[Мой код](https://github.com/DivinytyToffee/DivinytyToffee.github.io/tree/master/Laba3Web) на GitHub.

Comment: Можно разместить блоки с помощью сетки, а после уже смещать их через position: relative/absolute.

Comment: А объединять столбцы/строки  надо будет?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Просто к примеру в WPF и Qt, для растягивания элементов используется объединение строк и столбцов в GRID, можно ли такое делать с сеткой в materialize или это можно простым растягиванием элемента добится